# How to append to an array as a hash value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a CSV file that I am trying to process. I want to create a hash of some fields in the file but the code is only outputting the last record of the keys rather than the three records.

```
Season,Rk,Tm,G,PF,Yds,Ply,Y/P,TO,FL,1stD,Cmp,Att,Yds,TD,Int,NY/A,1stD,Att,Yds,TD,Y/A,1stD,Pen,Yds,1stPy,Sc%,TO%,EXP
2015,1,Carolina Panthers,16,500,5871,1060,5.5,19,9,357,300,501,3589,35,10,6.7,197,526,2282,19,4.3,136,103,887,24,42.9,9.6,125.65
2015,2,Arizona Cardinals,16,489,6533,1041,6.3,24,11,373,353,562,4616,35,13,7.8,237,452,1917,16,4.2,92,94,758,44,42.5,11.8,168.18
2014,19,Carolina Panthers,16,339,5547,1060,5.2,23,11,347,327,545,3511,23,12,6,199,473,2036,10,4.3,117,83,756,31,34.8,11.8,29.83
2014,24,Arizona Cardinals,16,310,5116,993,5.2,17,5,302,320,568,3808,21,12,6.4,191,397,1308,6,3.3,67,91,707,44,30.9,9.4,-15.68
2013,17,Arizona Cardinals,16,379,5542,1037,5.3,31,9,329,363,574,4002,24,22,6.5,205,422,1540,12,3.6,84,96,744,40,33,15.5,-11.6
2013,18,Carolina Panthers,16,366,5069,999,5.1,19,6,319,292,473,3043,24,13,5.9,169,483,2026,14,4.2,122,80,671,28,36.5,9.4,70.12
```

Here is the  code I have to create the hash:

```
require 'csv'

teams = {}

CSV.foreach("/home/rl/data/test-file.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
        teams[row.fields[2]] = Hash[row.headers[3..5].zip(row.fields[3..5])]
end

puts teams
```

This is my output. I was expecting three records per key where the key is the team:

```
{"Carolina Panthers"=>{:g=>16, :pf=>366, :yds=>5069}, "Arizona Cardinals"=>{:g=>16, :pf=>379, :yds=>5542}}
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. This seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: I thought I would get the records for 2015 and 2014 as well, I only got the 2013 records. I was expecting a nested grouping, e.g. for Carolina... "Carolina Panthers"=>{{:g=>16, :pf=>500, :yds=>5871},{:g=>16, :pf=>339, :yds=>5547},{:g=>16, :pf=>366, :yds=>5069}}

Comment: `"Carolina Panthers"=>{{:g=>16, :pf=>500, :yds=>5871},{:g=>16, :pf=>339, :yds=>5547},{:g=>16, :pf=>366, :yds=>5069}}` isn't valid. Perhaps you want `"Carolina Panthers"=>[{:g=>16, :pf=>500, :yds=>5871},{:g=>16, :pf=>339, :yds=>5547},{:g=>16, :pf=>366, :yds=>5069}]`?

Answer (score 1):

You get the last record for each group because you are actually rewriting it every time instead of adding it to the collection. To avoid it use:

```
# Push records to each collection by group instead of rewriting it
( teams[row.fields[2]]||=[] ) << Hash[row.headers[3..5].zip(row.fields[3..5])]
```

Comment: I changed as per suggestion...It returns me an empty {}...teams = Hash.new([])

CSV.foreach("/home/rl/data/test-file.csv", :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all) do |row|
        teams[row.fields[2]] << Hash[row.headers[3..5].zip(row.fields[3..5])]
end

Answer (score 1):

Changed teams to...

```
teams = Hash.new{|val,key| val[key] = []}
```

Output now as expected...

```
{"Carolina Panthers"=>[{:g=>16, :pf=>500, :yds=>5871}, {:g=>16, :pf=>339, :yds=>5547}, {:g=>16, :pf=>366, :yds=>5069}], "Arizona Cardinals"=>[{:g=>16, :pf=>489, :yds=>6533}, {:g=>16, :pf=>310, :yds=>5116}, {:g=>16, :pf=>379, :yds=>5542}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd write it:

```
require 'awesome_print'
require 'csv'

teams = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }
fields = [:g, :pf, :yds]
CSV.foreach( 
  'test.csv',
  headers: true,
  header_converters: :symbol,
  converters: :all
) do |row|
  teams[row[:tm]] << fields.zip(row.values_at(*fields)).to_h
end

ap teams
```

Which, when run and after reading the CSV, outputs:

```
{
  "Carolina Panthers" => [
    [0] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 500,
      :yds => 5871
    },
    [1] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 339,
      :yds => 5547
    },
    [2] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 366,
      :yds => 5069
    }
  ],
  "Arizona Cardinals" => [
    [0] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 489,
      :yds => 6533
    },
    [1] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 310,
      :yds => 5116
    },
    [2] {
      :g   => 16,
      :pf  => 379,
      :yds => 5542
    }
  ]
}
```

You're telling CSV to use symbols for the header names, which makes it really easy for you to access the values in the returned `row`, so do that. It's much easier to read and maintain that way.

[`Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) is the Ruby way of auto-creating array values for newly created key/value pairs.

Finally [Awesome Print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print), AKA `'ap'`, is a good tool for visualizing your data.

Comment: That is a nice solution. I like the fact that you reference the fields by name, always easier to reference...you somewhat preempted me having to look for this answer! ap is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you assign some value to the existing key in hash, value for this key is updated.

```
my_hash = {a: "me a", b: "me b"}  
my_hash[:a] = "another a"  
my_hash #=> {:a=>"another a", :b=>"me be"}
```

As you can see, in your example values for two keys `"Carolina Panthers"` and `"Arizona Cardinals"` are assigned to the last values in the list.

Comment: I thought it would create a one to many map. Seems I misunderstood the functionality.